# Bijection between $\mathscr P(\mathbb N)$ and $\mathscr P(\mathbb Z)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am struggling to find a bijection $\Phi: \mathscr P(\mathbb N) \rightarrow \mathscr P(\mathbb Z)$.

The book suggests considering $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ defined as $f(n) = \frac {(-1)^n(2n-1)+1}{4}$ as a hint, then goes on to say define $\Phi: \mathscr P(\mathbb N) \rightarrow \mathscr P(\mathbb Z)$ as $\Phi(X)=\{f(x):x \in X\}$ and show that $\Phi$ is a bijection.

I am a bit confused. Is $\Phi (X)$ not just the image of $X$ under $\Phi$, and since $\Phi$ hasn't been defined, how does this help me?

I see that $f=\{(1,0),(2,1),(3,-1),(4,2), (5,-2)...\}$ by plug and chug, and is indeed a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$.

I'm imagining $\Phi$ to be something which accepts sets $X \in \mathscr P(\mathbb N)$ and applies $g$ element-by-element. Any ideas for me?

(Tangentially related question, motivated by reading through some other posts : I see the following notation used here in some of the questions on mathstack: $y \in f(x)$. Are they trying to say that $y$ is in the range of $f$? Strictly speaking, I understood that the members of $f$ were ordered pairs.)

Comment: You are mixing $f$ and $g$. Replace $g$ two times with $f$.

Comment: I confused myself a bit with the notation. Fixed up now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $\Phi$ has been defined exactly as you imagine: it applies $f$ to each element of a set:
$$
\Phi(X) = \{f(x)\colon x \in X\}
$$
is the definition of $\Phi$ since $X$ is an element of the domain of $\Phi$ which is $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

You could write
$$
\Phi(X) = f(X)
$$
where $f(X)$ is the image of the set $X$ under the function $f$, while $\Phi(X)$ is the image of the element $X$.

Comment: Turns out I couldn't see the forest for the trees! I see now that $\Phi$ indeed takes all the sets in $\mathscr P(\mathbb N)$ and applies $f$ element-by-element.